# How do you get a list of changes from a Subversion repository by date range?

Tags: svn

What I would like is be able to generate a simple report that is the output of svn log for a certain date range.  Specifically, all the changes since 'yesterday'.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in Subversion besides grep-ing the svn log output for the timestamp?

Example:

```
svn -v log -d 2008-9-23:2008-9:24 > report.txt
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Very first hit by google for "svn log date range": http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2006-08/0737.shtml

> So `svn log <url> -r
>   {2008-09-19}:{2008-09-26}` will get
>   all changes for  the past week,
>   including today.

And if you want to generate reports for a repo, there's a solution: [Statsvn](http://statsvn.org/index.html).

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately this logs are not accurate and it is common problem http://apache.org/dev/version-control.html#date-revisions

Comment: For me, in Powershell, I had to put single quotes around the date range.

Comment: Keep in mind that subversion will assume 00:00:00 if you do not specify the time. So if you need every log including sep 19 and sep 26 you'll have to specify `{2008-09-19}:{2008-09-27}`

Comment: Actually, ***this page*** is the very first hit by google for "svn log date range"...

Answer (score 20):

You can use dates the same as you can use revision numbers. The syntax is {yyyy-mm-dd}. So, for all changes between 12:00am on September 23 and 12am on September 24, do:

```
svn log -v -r {2008-09-23}:{2008-09-24} > report.txt
```

Comment: you may want to add timestamps, otherwise it considers them both as 00:00:00 (and i think in local timezone?)  Example: `svn log -v -r {2008-09-23T00:00:00-0500}:{2008-09-24T:23:59:59-0500} > report.txt`

Answer (score 8):

```
svn log -r '{2013-9-23}:{2013-9-24}'
```

This is might be the correct syntex.
Quotes are required to get the correct results.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
svn log -r{2008-9-23}:{2008-9-24} > report.txt
```

Add a `--xml` before the `-r` if you want ot get the output in xml format for "easier" post processing.

Answer (score 5):

The -v is important if you want to see a list of the actual changes (over and above the log messages... if any! ;) )