# Source Control in Xcode, see latest since date

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn

Is there a way to check all the changes since a certain date?  We are using Subversion.  Thanks.

Comment: from command line svn or from within xcode?

Comment: if it's from the command line, there's a [duplicate question for that :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141599/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-changes-from-a-subversion-repository-by-date-range)